# Topology: nonempty set which does not have a point closest to the origin?

Tags: general-topology

What are some examples of nonempty set which have no points closest to the origin?

Comment: What do you mean by "closest" and "origin"?

Comment: How about the set $\{(1,0), (-1,0)\}$?

Comment: Interpreting your answer naturally leads to the most obvious answer: $\Bbb{R}^m$. Since it's so obvious, I must be misinterpreting your question.

Comment: @dbx In $\mathbb R^m$ the closest point to the origin is the origin itself. But what about $\mathbb R^m\setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: Like I said, interpreting your question naturally. Why not delete the origin then? At any rate, try to completely specify your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: For the discrete metric, any set that contains at least two points other than the origin has this property.

Comment: No ball centered at the origin can contain finitely many points of the set. Otherwise one of those points is closest. Therefore the set must have the origin as accumulation point. On the other hand, the origin itself must not belong to the set. Otherwise the origin is the closest point to the origin that belongs to the set. Therefore, that is the characterization of all sets that serve as your example: sets for which the origin is an accumulation point that doesn't belong to the set. One example is $\{1/n\}_{n=1,2,3,...}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A circle or a sphere of large radius.

Comment: Probably you should be more explicit about what you have in mind, for it does not seem to be an answer to the question.

Comment: I would say that in the event of a tie for distance, *all* the points are closest to the origin, not *none* of them. A better example is a set $S$ in which for every point $x\in S$, there's another point $y\in S$ closer to the origin than $x$.